# Python timeit and program output

Tags: python, time, timeit

Is there any way to use the timeit function to output both the function result and the time it took to process at the same time?

Right now I am using

```
timer = Timer('func()', 'from __main__ import func')
print timer.timeit(1)
```

But this just outputs the time and not the program output, which returns something at its end. I want it to output

```
FuncOutputGoesHere 13.2897528935
```

on the same line.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to take an average of the program by running it N times and then outputting the program result and its average time (a total of one output overall)

Comment: I seem to see a lot of deviation between people recommending timeit and people recommending time.time(). Which is better?

Comment: `timeit` uses `time.time()`, unless you are on windows, where it'll use `time.clock` (more accurate).

Comment: So timeit will provide me with the most accuracy?

Comment: My answer gives you *the same code* as what `timeit` uses. It'll be just as accurate.

Comment: Updated my answer; if you are running it more than once *anyway*, why not run it once more to capture the return value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmmmmm, hard to argue with that. Would I just divide it like so: timer.timeit(N)/N? Can I refer to functions dynamically? For instance, I can time a function dynamically by replacing the arguments in the string. Can I do the same for the actual function call?

Comment: Correct; the examples in the timeit documentation then multiply that value by 1,000,000 again to get a microsecond value instead of seconds, but they basically do `timer.timeit(N)/N`, yes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two options:

1. Include 'print' in your timed code. Ugly, but hey.

   ```
   timer = Timer('print func()', 'from __main__ import func')
   print timer.timeit(1)
   ```
2. If all you do is run your function once, then dispense with the `timeit` module altogether and time the code directly using the same method:

   ```
   import sys
   import time

   if sys.platform == "win32":
       # On Windows, the best timer is time.clock()
       default_timer = time.clock
   else:
       # On most other platforms the best timer is time.time()
       default_timer = time.time

   t0 = default_timer()
   output = func()
   t1 = default_timer()
   print output, t1 - t0
   ```

If you want to run the code multiple times, and produce the output, why not run the code once *outside* the timeit function? You are calling it more than once then already anyway:

```
    timer = Timer('func()', 'from __main__ import func')
    print timer.timeit(100),
    print func()
```

Answer (score 0):

The timeit module executes the statement passed. You could just print the result of the function:

```
timer = Timer('print func()', 'from __main__ import func')
print timer.timeit(1)
```

Comment: This would print it a million times, or however often the statement is executed, and also count the I/O overhead into the timings.

Comment: @delnan: he runs timer.timeit(1)... Make of that what you will. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know how to run it multiple times without it outputting multiple times; also I think I'd need to divide the result by the number of runtimes because it seems to be aggregate. It'd be ideal to run it a few times to get an average and output once.

Comment: Yes, it aggregates total runtime. See the timeit documentation.